# Inner SOQL query API Call

Tags: api, query, querylocator, inner

I am using a SOQL query that uses an inner query that returns the parent details along with all child details as one json record as API response. I would like to know how can nexturl be used when a parent record has more than 2000 child items.

Guidance would be really helpful. Thanks!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please use below format to fetch records using nextRecordsUrl and repeat it until you fetch all the records.

"nextRecordsUrl" : "/services/data/v55.0/query/01gD0000002HU6KIAW-2000"

Comment: Hi Nagesh. I have the scenario where in outer query and inner query both has nexturl present. Can you suggest the order in which this two pages should be fetched. I observed that if outer query's next page is fetched first then inner queries nexturl gets error outs whereas the vice versa works fine. I am not sure if it's just a coincidence or does it works this way only. Thanks!!